# How to fire an event from child component in vuex to any parent

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

So I have Component "X" as Parent Component   Or Component "Y" as
   Parent Component, "a" as child component fire one or many events
   Any child sibling or parent of "a" or "a" Itself can use that event
   I want to use "a" as an independent component

So I Have "X" component with its own

```
   state
   mutations
   actions 
   getters
```

And I have "a" component with its own

```
state    
mutations    
actions     
getters
```

"a" a.vue file looks like this

```
<template>
<div>
<app-select 
 @change.native="someevent()" 
 name="lineup_id" 
 v-model="$store.state.form.id" label="Select Id" 
:options="options"
 />
</div>
</template>
import AppSelect from "../AppSelect.vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options:[]
    };
  },
  components: {
    AppSelect,
  },
}
```

So I want to fire change event from child "a"
"X" and "Y" any parent get that event and do something with that event
I know how to do it with VUE

Comment: Yeah, that's event handling in VUE, and one more way you can use an event bus. 
But combining event bus and vuex state management is ok? I'm trying to finding the best way to do this event and state management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fist :** Don't use $state to get properties, [use mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-select 
      @change.native="someevent()" 
      name="lineup_id" 
      v-model="explicitPropertyName" label="Select Id" 
      :options="options"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import AppSelect from "../AppSelect.vue";
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed : {
      ...mapState(['explicitPropertyName'])
  }
  data() {
    return {
      options:[]
    };
  },
  components: {
    AppSelect,
  },
}
</script>
```

**Second :** Use bus event, see an example

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue()

const componentA = {
  template : `<button @click="emitMethod">Component A emit</button>`,
  methods: {
    emitMethod () {
       this.$eventBus.$emit('EVENT_NAME_FROM_A', { id: 12, pseudo: "Unicorn power A"});
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$eventBus.$on('EVENT_NAME_FROM_B', function (payload) {
       console.log('Emitted from component B, received in Component A', payload);
    });
  }
}

const componentB = {
  template : `<button @click="emitMethod">Component B emit</button>`,
  methods: {
    emitMethod () {
       this.$eventBus.$emit('EVENT_NAME_FROM_B', { id: 12, pseudo: "Unicorn power"});
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$eventBus.$on('EVENT_NAME_FROM_A', function (payload) {
       console.log('Emitted from component A, received in Component B', payload);
    });
  }
}

const vm = new Vue({ 
  el: "#app",
  components : {
    componentA,
    componentB
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$eventBus.$on('EVENT_NAME_FROM_B', function (payload) {
       console.log('Emitted from component B, received in Parent', payload);
    });
    
    this.$eventBus.$on('EVENT_NAME_FROM_A', function (payload) {
       console.log('Emitted from component A, received in Parent', payload);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app">
         <div>
            <component-b></component-b>
            <component-a></component-a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...mapState(['explicitPropertyName']) this looks good idea thanks